# PHP split array and get just one record/row

Tags: php

I am using the following code:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * from contacts where company_sequence = '".$customersequence."' and receive_accountsemails = 'yes' ";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
{
    $emails_list[] = $result2["email"];
}
```

This puts all email addresses from the contacts table into an array and then I send the emails to `implode(',',$emails_list)` so it separates each email address with a comma.

What is the best way to just get one email address into a variable on its own so I can insert each email sent into a different table? When I put `sentto` it wont do the whole array of emails.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use another foreach loop:

```
foreach($emails_list as $email)
{
   $user_email = $email;
   // Then you can send email in loops for each email. Target email is stored in $user_email or just $email
}
```

Comment: so i have the while loop that creates the arrays then outside of the loop use this code and send the emails/insert the data into the database within the foreach loop?

Comment: Yes exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not glue them all together with `join`but traverse them with

```
foreach ( $emails_list as $mail ) {
  // do something with each individual $mail
}
```